# How do you know if you have been killed by a headshot?

Tags: battlefield-3

What are the telltale characteristics that you have been pinged in the head? Or indeed, are there any?

Comment: Typically... you die. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are killed via a headshot, or you kill someone via a headshot, a little green target will appear next to the name of the person who was killed (your enemy if you killed someone, or you if you were killed).

[image: Demonstration]

Keep in mind this only shows up upon someone's death, if you headshot someone, or are headshot, and no-one dies, you won't know for sure if it was a headshot or not.

Comment: Huh. One of those things i've never noticed before

Comment: @Albort Ditto. Good to know.